# Download a video and automatically save in a folder

Tags: php, video, youtube

Using php, how can I download a video from youtube and when i click save the video goes directly to a folder I have already created?

I have this code:

```
 <label class="col-md-4" for="nome">Nome</label>//name that a give to the video//
 <label class="col-md-4" for="tipo">Tipo</label>//extension (.wmv, .mp4)//
 <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="nome" class="form-control" name="nome"/>//ABC example of a name
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control" name="tipo"> //extensions
            <option>wmv</option>
            <option>mp4</option>
            </select>
 </div>
 <label class="col-md-4" for="url">URL</label>
 <label class="col-md-4" for="caminho">Caminho</label>
 <input type="url" class="form-control" name="url" value="<?php "" 
               ?>"/> //example of a Url https://www.youtube.com/embed/LsG-rvQoErk
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="caminho" value="videos2/ABC.mp4">
```

This last line "input type="text" class="form-control" name="caminho" value="videos2/ABC.mp4"" doesnt exist but when I click to save I want that the video to be saved in a folder with the name "videos2" and when I go to see the video I want to see that it is saved on the folder.

How can I do this? Thank you

Comment: Have you done any research on how to actually download a video from YouTube?

Comment: Do a google on "How do I rip off videos from YouTube"

Answer (score 0):

You can get youtube video downloading url using below url

```
http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id='+{VIDEO_ID}+'&asv=3&el=detailpage&hl=en_US
```

and from github you can get youtube video downloading script in php at

```
https://github.com/jeckman/YouTube-Downloader
```